# Double answer upon single post (with browser history included)

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro, duplicate-answers

I just submitted an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084262), it came up with the CAPTCHA check, then I clicked the submit button once. Two same answers appeared 30 seconds apart in time.   I've never had this happen before so thought it worth mentioning.

I've deleted one of the duplicate posts so only high rep will see them both

**Update:**

My browser history shows the following sequential actions during the process of submission - I have left nothing out.
The first entry is me doing my *ahem* "research" on Wikipedia

- 11:38p http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell#Pipeline
- 11:40p https://stackoverflow.com/captcha?s=2e53a58c-a97f-4861-b90d-9e663d52e447
- 11:41p [how to use piping in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084262/how-to-use-piping-in-c/3098794#3098794)
- 11:41p [how to use piping in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084262/how-to-use-piping-in-c)
- 11:42p https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

and the last is me visiting meta to post this question.

I'm using Chrome 5.0.375.70

Answer (score 1):

There have been times where I posted an answer and *meant* to edit the post but hit the `back` button instead. Click `post` the second time and, boom, two duplicate answers.

I can't say this is what happened to you but I would have sworn up-and-down that I did not hit the back button but my browser history said differently.

Comment: updated the question with browser history

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce this.